# Add column to SQL Server CE table using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to add a new column to a table in my CE database using C# code.

This SQL works in SSMS to add to a standard SQL database table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = N'sent' AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'QAReports')) BEGIN 
  ALTER TABLE QAReports ADD [Sent] bit NULL;
END
```

But when I try to run the same sql in C# I get an error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = IF ]

My code that I'm using to execute the SQL above is:

```
bool retVal = true;
try
{
    using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    retVal = false;
}
return retVal;
```

Is there a way to do what I want to do.

Is there a better way.  I'm trying to upgrade a database on an end-users installation if they need it.  I check a value in the database that tells me what app version was last used on it.  Then I want to run the SQL to add the required fields and then update the value in the database for the app version.

Comment: SQL CE does not have procedural statements like `IF`. You have to break your SQL into two commands, `ExecuteScalar('SELECT Count(*) ...')`, then if the result is > 0, `ExecuteNonQuery('ALTER TABLE ...')`.

Comment: That's a shame.  Thanks @DourHighArch.  If you add this as an "answer" rather than a comment, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Procedural SQL has significant overhead, do not use it unless you need it. If you need it, SQL CE is not a good choice. I did not write an answer as I didn't know how to query SQL CE schema and there are other problems with your code; e.g. you should not be catching exceptions and returning Booleans. If you can clean up your code, post it as an answer.